# jGroups is not finding other computers

Tags: jgroups

I am using jGroups to be able to determine the master for multiple instances of of an app I have, however, all works well on the same computer, but other computers on the same subnet does not get notified. I tried many options I found on the net such as starting with -Djgroups.bind.addr=
I also started two instances on different machines (windows) and the other machine does not get notified:

java -cp jgroups-4.0.3.Final.jar -Djgroups.bind_addr=10.1.2.80 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.demos.Draw

java -cp jgroups-4.0.3.Final.jar -Djgroups.bind_addr=10.1.10.82 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.demos.Draw

Any help would be much appreciated.
BTW- I also created a channel with the udp.xml: xml at:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.infinispan/infinispan-core/7.0.3.Final/default-configs/default-jgroups-udp.xml

Answer (score 1):

I suggest go through the items in this checklist [1]. Also set `GMS.print_local_addr` to true and confirm that the instances bind to the correct bind address (e.g. not `127.0.0.1`).

Note that if you start `Draw` without arguments, default `udp.xml` included in jgroups.jar will be used. You need to start Draw with the `-props` argument pointing to the `udp.xml` you customized.

[1] https://github.com/belaban/workshop/blob/master/slides/admin.adoc#problem-1-members-don-t-find-each-other