# jGroups simple example does not work anymore

Tags: ubuntu, network-programming, jgroups

After some dev, I cannot make the [simple example](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial/#_running_a_demo_program) `Draw` to work anymore. The `Receiver`/`Sender` test does work though. Moreover, the `Draw` test works if run in a virtual machine on my computer.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I suspect that I changed, somehow, some config file(s) that may affect JGroups. The problem is that when I run `Draw` from two different terminals, the nodes do not connect (or view each other) but stay in two different clusters.

I have seen [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526164/jgroups-is-not-finding-other-computers) but it did not help.

I know very few about networking and networking configuration on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had activated [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html), which blocked the nodes from connecting to each other (you can see its status with `sudo ufw status`. After running `sudo ufw disable` (which is the default state on Ubuntu) the example ran perfectly. If you need to keep it enabled, you may have to add a rule for JGroups to run the example.